# Multiple case condition

Tags: sql

How do i achieve the multiple case condition? The below say invalid syntax

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN b.SnapshotDtm = getdate() THEN        
       CASE WHEN (GenderCd = 'F' And EthnicGroupCd = 'N/A') THEN 
         (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_M - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_F) * 
                 (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/FiscalYearDayNbr)
        else CASE WHEN (EthnicGroupCd in(2,3,5)) THEN 
              (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_White - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_235) * 
                 (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/FiscalYearDayNbr) 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN (GenderCd = 'F' And EthnicGroupCd = 'N/A') THEN
                    (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_M - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_F) * 
                         (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/SnapshotDaysOfYearNbr)
        ELSE CASE WHEN (EthnicGroupCd in(2,3,5)) THEN 
                        (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_White - 
                          TechAnnualizedExitsPct_235) * 
                          (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/SnapshotDaysOfYearNbr) 
            end) as TechExitsDeltaCnt,
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get: `Invalid syntax near ..` ?

Comment: near the ')' at  end) as TechExitsDeltaCnt

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: syntax error: )
  correction: END END END END )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nesting is off. You're missing a few `END`s:

```
SUM(
    CASE WHEN b.SnapshotDtm = getdate() THEN         
        CASE WHEN (GenderCd = 'F' And EthnicGroupCd = 'N/A') THEN (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_M - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_F) * (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/FiscalYearDayNbr)
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN (EthnicGroupCd in(2,3,5)) THEN (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_White - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_235) * (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/FiscalYearDayNbr)
            END 
        END
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN (GenderCd = 'F' And EthnicGroupCd = 'N/A') THEN (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_M - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_F) * (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/SnapshotDaysOfYearNbr)
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN (EthnicGroupCd in(2,3,5)) THEN (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_White - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_235) * (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/SnapshotDaysOfYearNbr) 
            END
        END
    END) as TechExitsDeltaCnt,
```

Comment: We don't know for sure where the `END`s should come in at.

Comment: This seems pretty logical though @RaduGheorghiu, if you look at the expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually missing a few `END`s for each opened `CASE`. Try this:

```
SUM(CASE 
       WHEN b.SnapshotDtm = getdate() 
          THEN CASE 
             WHEN (GenderCd = 'F' And EthnicGroupCd = 'N/A') 
                THEN (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_M - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_F) * (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/FiscalYearDayNbr)
                ELSE CASE 
                   WHEN (EthnicGroupCd in(2,3,5)) 
                      THEN (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_White - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_235) * (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/FiscalYearDayNbr) 
                      ELSE CASE 
                         WHEN (GenderCd = 'F' And EthnicGroupCd = 'N/A') 
                            THEN (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_M - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_F) * (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/SnapshotDaysOfYearNbr)
                            ELSE CASE 
                               WHEN (EthnicGroupCd in(2,3,5)) 
                                  THEN (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_White - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_235) * (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/SnapshotDaysOfYearNbr)
                                 END
                           END
                     END
               END
     END) AS TechExitsDeltaCnt
```

Answer (score 2):

**Else And END** tag Missed

```
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.SnapshotDtm = getdate() 
THEN        
 CASE WHEN (GenderCd = 'F' And EthnicGroupCd = 'N/A') 
     THEN 
       (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_M - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_F) * 
     (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/FiscalYearDayNbr)
      else
     CASE WHEN (EthnicGroupCd in(2,3,5))
      THEN 
      (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_White - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_235) * 
       (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/FiscalYearDayNbr) -------------Else And END TAG is Missing
 ELSE 
       CASE WHEN (GenderCd = 'F' And EthnicGroupCd = 'N/A') 
       THEN
       (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_M - TechAnnualizedExitsPct_F) * 
        (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/SnapshotDaysOfYearNbr)
         ELSE CASE WHEN (EthnicGroupCd in(2,3,5)) THEN 
         (TechAnnualizedExitsPct_White - 
         TechAnnualizedExitsPct_235) * 
         (TechRepresentCnt_F)/ (365/SnapshotDaysOfYearNbr) -------------Else And END TAG is Missing
           end) as TechExitsDeltaCnt,
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far. From the question it is unclear exactly where to add the `end`. You have chosen to follow the indentation, which has a fairly good chance of beeing correct. Also, you are the only one so far to point out the missing `else` clauses. Else clauses are not mandatory, but you usually want one anyway.

Comment: I disagree @KlasLindbäck. The expressions make little sense with this nesting (`GenderCd = 'F' And EthnicGroupCd = 'N/A'` in both outer AND inner case. The second would never get hit). Also, as you mention, `else` is neither required nor wanted every time. But it's good that all answers have unique solutions anyway ;-)

Comment: @Mackan Good point! You get +1 for analysing the expressions and for your crystal clear indentation!